# Can't efficiently scroll iniside React native application

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

I am just a beginner and has been constantly working on a project that needs to be completed soon. I have fetched over a 5000 list of data through an API however, the list is not efficient in scrolling and thus breaks the application. I have been searching for `FlatList`  component in `React Native` which i cant implement properly on my Project. 
Can someone please provide suggestions on how to tackle this problem. I have attached my Source Code below-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import GalleryDetail from './GalleryDetail';

class GalleryList extends Component {

state = { photos: []};

componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    .then(response => this.setState({ photos: response.data })).
    catch((error)=> console.warn("fetch Error: ", error));
}

renderPhotos() {
    return this.state.photos.map( photos => 
        <GalleryDetail key={photos.id} photos= {photos}/>
    );
}


render () {
    return (
        <View>
            <ScrollView>
                {this.renderPhotos()}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
}

export default GalleryList;
```

**Where my GalleryDetail is**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card';
import CardSection from './CardSection';

const GalleryDetail = (props)=> {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection style = {styles.headerContentStyle}>
                <Image
                style={styles.thumbnailStyle}
                source = {{ uri: props.photos.thumbnailUrl}}/>
                <Text style= {styles.textStyle}>{props.photos.title}</Text>
            </CardSection>
        </Card>
    );
};

const styles = {
    headerContentStyle: {
       flexDirection: 'column',
       justifyContent: 'space-around'
   },

   thumbnailStyle: {
       height: 50,
       width: 50
   },

    textStyle: {
       textAlign: 'right',
       marginLeft: 3,
        marginRight: 3,
    }
}

export default GalleryDetail;
```

Sorry for not providing proper Snippet. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should make your network call in [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) as the documentation explains.

Second, don't use the ScrollView because it's not performant and when using a FlatList, you don't need a ScrollView anymore.

Third, update GalleryDetail to use props.photo instead of props.photos as you are passing a single object to each row (the plural makes it counter intuitive). And access the data through the `item` property in the photo object:

```
const GalleryDetail = (props)=> {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection style = {styles.headerContentStyle}>
                <Image
                style={styles.thumbnailStyle}
                source = {{ uri: props.photo.thumbnailUrl}}/>
                <Text style= {styles.textStyle}>{props.photo.title}</Text>
            </CardSection>
        </Card>
    );
};
```

Finally, use the following snippet

```
  render() {
    if (!this.state.photos) {
      return <ActivityIndicator/>;
    }

    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.photos}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this.renderPhoto}
      />
    );
  }

  keyExtractor = (photo, index) => photo.id;

  renderPhoto = ({item}) => {
    return < GalleryDetail photo={item} />;
  };
```

Comment: Hi @Carlos,
Thankyou so much for responding. It really helped me alot.
As per your suggestions, I implemented the 1st and 2nd opinions. However, for third, i just wanted to say that the reason for using _photos_ as the keyword and not _photo_ is due to the URL i am using as it uses photos inside it. 

However, upon trying both of them, it does not displays the content onto the screen yet it adds the content body with all the stylings on the screen. 

It will be great if you can provide me a little bit more of suggestion on how to deal with this situation.

Comment: I just checked your API response in your code and and the urls are not https. That won't load in iOS and it's in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#1-enable-app-transport-security. It's only going to work for Android.

Comment: Upon implementing all the suggestions and code as described in the snippet, it wont result in showing up the Images and Text (from GalleryDetail) inside the application. I can't figure out the reason as no error pops up.
And yes, i only want to use the API link for an android application for now as i need to put some hands-on experience on react native, but i dont want to leave at this spot. 

@carlos

Comment: I made a slight change in renderPhoto because the FlatList wraps each item in an item property. It should work now.

Comment: Wowww!! It works yeayy !
Thanks so much for your consistent help and suggestions @Carlos.

Comment: @JatinSuneja, you are welcome :) If that was right, please mark it as the right answer :)